# R: arrays - reducing length (generalization)

Tags: arrays, r, generalization

I need to reduce length (generalize) an array in R. For example, I have hi-resolution data like this...

```
my_array=array(c(sample(0:9,32, replace=TRUE)), dim=c(4,4,2))
> my_array
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    8    2
[2,]    3    5    4    6
[3,]    2    8    9    6
[4,]    1    0    9    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    7    9    7
[2,]    9    4    9    8
[3,]    8    6    7    8
[4,]    7    6    9    9
```

...and I need to "generalise" it to low-resolution using the mean function like this:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2.75 4.00
[2,] 2.75 8.25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 5.75 8.25
[2,] 6.75 8.25
```

Simply, 4 values of the original array (positions [1,1];[1,2];[2,1];[2,2]) form 1 value (average) in resulting array in [1,1] position. I have tried using "apply" over the array, but I am not able to cope with "non-standard" margins. Is there any more complex function like apply in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution very similar to the one adapted by @crwang but generalized into a function:

```
reduceMatrix <- function(x, rown, coln, fun = mean, ...) {
  out <- matrix(NA,  nrow=nrow(x)/rown, ncol=ncol(x)/coln)
  for (i in 1:(nrow(x)/rown)) {
    for (j in 1:(ncol(x)/coln)) {
      indi <- c(rown*i-1, rown*i)
      indj <- c(coln*j-1, coln*j)
      out[i, j] <- fun(x[indi, indj], ...)  
    }
  }
  out
}
```

The function works on 2d arrays, so you can apply them over the 3rd dimenssion of `my_array`:

```
set.seed(10)
my_array <- array(c(sample(0:9,32, replace=TRUE)), dim=c(4,4,2))

lapply(seq_len(dim(my_array)[3]), 
       function(a) reduceMatrix(my_array[,,a], 2, 2))

[[1]]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.5  4.0
[2,]  3.5  4.5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.00 5.25
[2,] 5.25 3.75
```

The idea of this approach is having a function that works either for stand alone matrices (in 3D arrays, lists, etc), and also an easier selection of number of rows (`rown`) and columns (`coln`) to be aggregated, as well as the applied function (`mean`, `median`, `sum`) and other arguments (e.g. `na.rm`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment on this but I do not have enough reputation to do so, so I post my comment here.

I found a similar question and answer [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-resample-or-resize-matrix-td804748.html).

A solution for your problem, based on the answer I found, could be:

```
my_array=array(c(sample(0:9,32, replace=TRUE)), dim=c(4,4,2))
my_array

rmean <- array(c(matrix(0,2,2),matrix(0,2,2)),dim=c(2,2,2))  # result array
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2){
    for (k in 1:2){
      rmean[,,k][i, j] <- mean(my_array[,,k][c(-1,0) + 2 * i, c(-1,0) + 2 * j])
    }
  }
}
rmean
```

Results:

```
> my_array
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    8    4    4    9
[2,]    0    7    9    5
[3,]    2    7    2    6
[4,]    9    5    8    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    4    7
[2,]    3    7    0    6
[3,]    2    8    9    3
[4,]    7    9    1    9

> rmean
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.75 6.75
[2,] 5.75 5.50

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 3.25 4.25
[2,] 6.50 5.50
```